# How do i connect to database using 'sqlplus / as sysdba' rather than 'sqlplus sys/<password> as sysdba'?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sysdba

username/password less connectivity to oracle database.

i tried to add "SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=none" in /dbs/sqlnet.ora location.

Comment: Step 1: Is SQLPlus running on the same machine as the database?

Comment: Are you logged in as the oracle software owner on the database server?

Comment: logged in as oracle and yes, SQLPLUS running on the same machine as the database.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle wallet is definitely an option for password-less access to a database - I can't guarantee these pointers will work exactly for your specific situation but it should at least point you in a direction. Please note that of course you will of course need to take ownership of your own security considerations.

The following is an approach I know works on a Linux hosted environment but as this is Oracle provided functionality there should be a variation that should likely work similarly if you are running your db on Windows

(all values in square brackets eg [ORACLE_WALLET_DIR] should be replaced with your own values)

**sqlnet.ora**

```
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY = [ORACLE_WALLET_DIR])
     )
   )

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_VERSION = 0
```

As the "oracle" user I set up the Oracle wallet as follows:

```
mkdir [ORACLE_WALLET_DIR]
chmod 700 [ORACLE_WALLET_DIR]   
orapki wallet create -wallet "[ORACLE_WALLET_DIR]" -pwd "[walletPassword]" -auto_login_local

mkstore -wrl "[ORACLE_WALLET_DIR]" -createCredential [ORACLE_SID] SYS "[ORACLE_DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD]"
```

(you'll likely be prompted to provide the wallet password on the mkstore command)

then to connect to my[ORACLE_SID] I go

```
sudo su - oracle
sqlplus /nolog
conn / as sysdba
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: @JEI - anytime, always happy to help such an appreciative person :D